# Keep columns of a dataframe whose name is an integer and satisfies a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, with columns whose name is either words, or dates. I want to keep only the columns with words in their names, or some specific dates. In particular, the dataframe has columns "Price" , "Origin", "Company", and with the years 1980 to 2008, and I want to keep only the ones with the years from 1996 to 2008, and the ones with words as column names.

This is the code that I wrote, but I am pretty sure there is a shorter and more elegant way to do this:

```
columns_to_keep = list()    
for c in df.columns.values:
    if c.isdigit():
        if int(c) > 1995:
            columns_to_keep.append(c)
    else:
        columns_to_keep.append(c)
df_copy = df[columns_to_keep]
```

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't the years data within the rows that you can query and filter by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be to use list comprehension and create a new list on the fly:

```
df.columns
Index(['Price', 'Origin', 'Company', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984',
       '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993',
       '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002',
       '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008'],
      dtype='object')

columns_to_keep = [col for col in df.columns if not (col.isdigit() and int(col) <= 1995)]

['Price',
 'Origin',
 'Company',
 '1996',
 '1997',
 '1998',
 '1999',
 '2000',
 '2001',
 '2002',
 '2003',
 '2004',
 '2005',
 '2006',
 '2007',
 '2008']
```

Changing the type to string before the `isdigit` gets around any "col is an integer" error:

```
columns_to_keep = [col for col in df.columns if not (str(col).isdigit() and int(col) <= 1995)]
```

Comment: Your list comprehension is raising an error. col is an integer and has no isdigit method.

Comment: @TedPetrou Most likely because your column names are integers, from OP's code, it seems that he/she has string column names.

Comment: Yes, all the column names are strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFrame.filter for this. That method also supports regex so you have the power of matching whatever pattern you like.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[1,2,3], 'Origin':['Earth','Mars','Pluto'], 'Company':['SpaceX', 'SpaceY', 'SpaceZ'], '1980':[100,101,102], '2000':[50,51,52]})

years = ['%d'%x for x in range(1996,2009)]
pattern = r'(?:[a-zA-Z]+|'+'|'.join(y)+')'
newdf = df.filter(regex=pattern)
```